# Mac OSX (Moutain Lion) install didn't finish with ROS Eclectic

Tags: macos-mountain-lion, ros-electric, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got the following error when tried to do the rosdep install with the full package in ROS...

Error: No available formula for gtest
Failed to install gtest!
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 16, in 
sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 229, in rosinstall_main
options.catkinpp)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 100, in cmd_generate_ros_files
subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/shyamal/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

Why is ROS broken on Mountain Lion?  If it is still broken, how do I uninstall all the tools that I just installed to get all the way up to the rosdep install command?  If you have any bugs with the OSX version, could I please help to make it work because I hate using ROS on Ubuntu (currently the defacto OS of choice)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49577/mac-osx-(moutain-lion)-install-didn%27t-finish-with-ros-eclectic/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/42335/mac-os-x-install-error-no-available-formula-for-gtest/

You can install it manually, but until we figure out a better way of distributing it that is the best solution.

We don't want to distribute gtest with ROS because on Ubuntu there is a package which distributes the source for us.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1